# Not able to hide Toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Toplevel window for which I want to toggle the visibility.
It is a listbox of options, which is supposed to dissapear when you click on one of the 10 options.

The problem I have, is when the Toplevel window (called 'newW') appears, it does not go into a hidden state when it loses focus. Even though the 'newW' window is bind to that event.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

#Create Menu
mb = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = mb)
root.option_add('*tearOff', False)
bk = Menu(mb)
mb.add_cascade(menu = bk, label = 'Edit')

#Create seperate window to show background  options
newW = Toplevel(root)
newW.overrideredirect(True)

#Create Listbox to newW
lb = Listbox(newW)
lb.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
for x in range(10):
    lb.insert(END, x)

#Define function to toggle visibility of Toplevel window
def show(e=None):
    if newW.state() == 'withdrawn':
        newW.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(root.winfo_rootx(),     root.winfo_rooty()))
        newW.deiconify()
        newW.selection_clear()
        return
    newW.withdraw()

#Add item to Menu button that is suppposed to show / hide Toplevel window
bk.add_command(label = 'Test Me', command =  show)

#Bind visibility of Toplevel Window on focus
newW.bind('<FocusOut>', newW.withdraw())

root.mainloop()
```

So to be clear, what I want to do, is make the newW window hidden when I click back on the root window (hence the FocusOut). It only works when I press the 'Try Me' button, meaning it toggles on and off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign the return value of a call to `newW.withdraw()`, which is `None` to the event of losing focus. You should use `newW.withdraw` without parentheses. However, if you do that, the event object will also be passed to `newW.withdraw`, which can't accept it. You can use a lambda function to intercept the event object.

So replace

```
newW.bind('<FocusOut>', newW.withdraw())
```

with

```
newW.bind('<FocusOut>', lambda e: newW.withdraw())
```

Also, you can add `newW.focus_set()` to the code in which you let `newW` appear, so that any click outside of `newW` makes it lose focus and trigger the event.